# Qt Compiler Error

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Qt 5.1 VS2012 , but I do not have VS2012 installed. when I want to compile a project, I get an error saying that no compiler configuration is present. Is there a way not to install VS2012 completely ? forexample just installing its compiler alone ?

Comment: Why didn't you get the bundle that comes with MinGW if you don't want to install VS?

Comment: It does not need to install an additional software package?

Comment: No, comes with GCC as a compiler.

Comment: anyway, in my case there is no other way except installing VS completely? Ive read somewhere that windows SDK package comes with vs compiler and something like that. Is there a solution like this ?

Comment: Either get and install VS Express or get the GCC build of Qt together with the compiler. You can do a standalone installation of GCC, but for MSVC I am not sure...